# Module error in imports using python/vscode

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, conda

I changed my computer in the last month and after installing python in Ubuntu 22.04 I notice a problem that until now I couldn't solve.
When I install a package - mostly using pip - sometimes it works and others not.
In this moment, my VSCode has a warning telling me that I didnt install requests:
[vscode print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/475Hr.png)

but it is actually installed. If i run my program using the "Run" tool - ctrl + f5 - shows me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OoR6.png)

However if I only do python3 app.py it works..
I don't know what is happening and it is really annoying

Comment: You need to setup VSCode to work with virtual environments - that is standard practice for python development. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: If worse comes to worse you can [manually-specify-an-interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) in order to use the correct environment - however, in general do not use your "system python" and always use a virtual environment. In your current situation, you probably are using your "system python", and for whatever reason either 1) VSCode is not using that python, or 2) you are installing your pip packages somewhere else without realizing it.

Comment: Installing via `python -m pip install` rather than `pip install` is another safeguard which helps avoid installing packages to a different python environment.

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, an image.

Comment: as @topsail said, it worked perfectly. When I change my interpreter for conda, it work's. I still don't understanding why my pip install is not installing in my system python (even before i install conda), but at least it solved my problem